# Deep link work in iPad, but not in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, deeplink

I'm working on an old iOS application made in Objective C. I have an html button with a deep link inside a WebView (don't ask why, I have to do this way, not my choice). This Deep Link should open the inApp page of subscription of my app.
It works well when I run my application on iPad but nothing happen when I try it on iPhone (regardless of iOS version or device).
It's not me who implemented the deep link code, so I can't be sure that it's ok. I search a lot, but I didn't find anyone who had the same issue.
If you need more information to help me, let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "deeplink".  The tag provides no help.

Comment: Deep link is kind of url that allows you to open your app in spécifique page. It can be click outside the app, then iOS detect it is for your app and open it. In App, you juste have to parse the url to know witch page to open.

Comment: OK good.  Please provide the link in the button.

Comment: I don't think it will help you, those url are pretty simple: ofv2://abonnement
"ofv2" is the identifier of my app
'abonnement" is the key word for my app to know which page to open